# Best way to implement drop down UI in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu

[image]
I am trying to implement a drop down UI in my project, and noticed that Cocoa doesn't offer a standard drop down, only a picker.  What is the best way to create a dropdown menu like this in iOS in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ios there is no dropdown option. The best way is go with `UIPopoverController`. refer the below links it will help you.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle

Comment: @JoshO'Connor what did you end with? Have the same requirement. The dropdown in the top image looks amazing.